# Elasticsearch 5.5, Ошибка [nested] nested object under path [values] is not of nested type, как исправить?

Tags: php7, elasticsearch

Имеется сервер Elasticsearch 5.5.3 и PHP клиент elasticsearch/elasticsearch 5.5.0

На нем создается базовая структура таким запросом:

```
[
    'index' => 'timpo',
    'type' => 'adverts',
    'id' => 0,
    'body' => []
]
```

Далее делается индексация документов такими запросами:

```
[
    'index' => 'timpo'
    'type' => 'adverts'
    'id' => 1
    'body' => [
        'id' => 1
        'title' => 'Продажа от админа'
        'description' => '11111'
        'price' => '50'
        'type' => 1
        'country' => 8
        'region' => 865732
        'city' => 783263
        'district' => null
        'categories' => [
            0 => 3
            1 => 1
            2 => 2
        ]
        'values' => [
            0 => [
                'characteristic' => 1
                'value_string' => 'Белый'
                'value_int' => 0
            ]
            1 => [
                'characteristic' => 2
                'value_string' => 'Пластик'
                'value_int' => 0
            ]
            2 => [
                'characteristic' => 3
                'value_string' => '128'
                'value_int' => 128
            ]
            3 => [
                'characteristic' => 4
                'value_string' => '222'
                'value_int' => 222
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

После чего в индексе появляются документы вида:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "77",
  "description": "765678768",
  "price": "88",
  "type": 4,
  "country": 73,
  "region": 2614219,
  "city": 2613660,
  "categories": [
    2,
    1
  ],
  "values": [
    {
      "characteristic": 1,
      "value_string": "Белый",
      "value_int": 0
    },
    {
      "characteristic": 2,
      "value_string": "Золото",
      "value_int": 0
    },
    {
      "characteristic": 3,
      "value_string": "256",
      "value_int": 256
    }
  ]
}
```

Далее если делаю такой запрос на выборку, все корректно отрабатывает:

```
[
    'index' => 'timpo'
    'type' => 'adverts'
    'body' => [
        '_source' => [
            0 => 'id'
            1 => 'title'
            2 => 'price'
            3 => 'description'
        ]
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    0 => [
                        'term' => [
                            'categories' => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                    1 => [
                        'term' => [
                            'type' => '1'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

При попытке выполнить такой запрос, с блоком nested падает ошибка `[nested] nested object under path [values] is not of nested type`.

```
[
    'index' => 'timpo'
    'type' => 'adverts'
    'body' => [
        '_source' => [
            0 => 'id'
            1 => 'title'
            2 => 'price'
            3 => 'description'
        ]
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    0 => [
                        'term' => [
                            'categories' => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                    1 => [
                        'term' => [
                            'type' => '1'
                        ]
                    ]
                    2 => [
                        'nested' => [
                            'path' => 'values'
                            'query' => [
                                'bool' => [
                                    'must' => [
                                        0 => [...]
                                        1 => [...]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Предполагаю что эластик просит задать тип для nested объекта или как то подругому построить запрос, но совершенно не представляю как это сделать, документация ничего не прояснило так как я незнаю на какой исходной версии этот скрипт работал корректно и непонятно с какой версией сравнивать.
Прошу помощи...

Comment: `Предполагаю что эластик просит задать тип для nested объекта` - да, в маппинге надо указать для values `"type": "nested"`. Или можно попробовать, условно, искать так `'term' => [ 'values.characteristic' => 2 ]`

Comment: @InDevX как это сделать, всмысле маппинг?

Comment: @InDevX на каком этапе это делается, при индексации или при создании структуры?

Comment: При создании индекса. [Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) это описание структуры документа. У вас же некое подобие динамического маппинга (поля создаются "на лету", без описания типов и т.п.). Можно попробовать обновить маппинг для nested, [пример](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#_customizing_detected_date_formats)

Comment: @InDevX эти ссылки не работают, они для РФ заблокированы...

Comment: vpn вам в помощь... ссылки на офф гайд

Comment: @InDevX из за того что я возможно не знаю основ эластика, по ссылке на пример с `dynamic_date_formats` я совершенно не понял причем тут `nested`...

Comment: На то он и пример... `{ "mappings": { "properties": { "values": { "type": "nested" } } } }` что-то в этом роде должно быть